# how can run websockets:serve on hosting laravel

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

Work on a laravel site with real-time notifications using the laravel-websocket library from:

`https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction`

On the local server I have to run the following command for it to work:

`php artisan websockets:serve`

`Starting the WebSocket server on port 6001...`

Now I have uploaded the website to cloudways hosting

How can I implement the command to always run the server?

`php artisan websockets:serve`

Comment: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/supervisord-now-available-on-cloudways/ https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/basic-usage/starting#keeping-the-socket-server-running-with-supervisord

Comment: than you I will add supervisor and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using VPS, I think you should install a supervisor to help out running your WebSocket. Here example that I found [click](https://ghostscypher.medium.com/running-laravel-websockets-in-production-def368a84d56)

Comment: thank you , i will add supervisor and try